# Trying to set download directory in python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a process I have to do every day. Where I have to download a file and process it. Most everything works however when selenium downloads the file it ends up in my downloads folder. I would like the file to download to a folder local to the python script, a data folder in in the same folder as the script. I have made sure that my cmd instance has been running locally. Here I have provided the init function for my Browser class.

```
    def __init__ (self, driver: str):
        self.service = Service(driver)
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        prefs = {"download.default_directory":".\\data\\"}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.service, options=options)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you,
-Mark

Comment: Does your existing code throw any errors?

Comment: I think you just need to change ```options= options``` to ```chrome_options=options```

Comment: I changed that and I got an error. WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chrome_options'

Comment: Could you provide how you actually download the file? 
Such as via action like .click() or maybe requests.get(url)

Comment: OKay that's because they removed ```chrome_options``` after [4.10](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e). Your code looks okay, just change the directory to absolute instead of [relative location](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) and make sure your webriver and selenium are latest versions

Comment: making it a absolute instead of relative worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach, first create a method, where you can get file:

```
import platform
from os.path import expanduser
import os


def download_folder(filename):
    home = expanduser("~")
    download_path = home + os.sep + "Downloads"
    if platform.system() is "Darwin" or "Linux":
        return download_path + "/" + filename
    else:
        return download_path + "\\" + filename
```

This is will return you, your downloads path and you mention your file name as well..
and you use that function to access your file.